# Axiomatic Schema Substitution

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, axioms, hilbert-calculus

With the following axiomatic schema (A1 - A3)

$(A1)(B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B))$

$(A2)((B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow D)) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow D)))$

$(A3)(((\lnot C) \rightarrow (\lnot B)) \rightarrow (((\lnot C) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C))
$

I'm trying to prove that $\vdash(\lnot B \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B$

I've tried doing the following, using instances of the above:

1. (A2) - $(((\lnot B) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow ((\lnot B))) \rightarrow (((\lnot B) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((\lnot B) \rightarrow (\lnot B))))$
2. (A1) - $((\lnot B) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow (\lnot B)))$
3. (2,3 MP) - $(((\lnot B) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow ((\lnot B) \rightarrow (\lnot B)))$
4. (A3) - $(((\lnot B) \rightarrow (\lnot B)) \rightarrow (((\lnot B) \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow B))$

First off, I know this is quite simple stuff but I can't for the life of me find a way to find an antecedent to 4. using the above schema. So I'm wondering if there's something that's obviously incorrect about the process that I'm using? Is my substitution of a $B$ wf with a $(\lnot B)$ wf okay? I'm using Mendelson's book btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D=B$ in $(A2)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
((B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow B)))
\end{eqnarray*}
The first clause is true ... its $(A1)$ ... so by modus ponens
\begin{eqnarray*}
 ((B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow B))
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sub $ C \rightarrow B$ for $C$
\begin{eqnarray*}
 ((B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow B))
\end{eqnarray*}
Again the first clause is true ... its $(A1)$ ... so by modus ponens
\begin{eqnarray*}
(B \rightarrow B)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sub $ \lnot B $ for $B$ ... so
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot B)
\end{eqnarray*}
So ... your fourth line & MP will give you the required result.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you can substitute in to $((B\rightarrow C)\rightarrow (B \rightarrow B))$ also?. For some reason I was under the impression you could only substitute from the axiomatic schema and not from any derived consequence of MP.

Comment: I would need to see your text book to be sure .... but usually you start with the axioms of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ukasiewicz_logic ... & then you make deductions using MP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens

Comment: @ev350 It is reverse engineering the proof. You aim to derive $(\neg B\to \neg B)$ so that you can use MP with your line $(4)$ to complete the proof.  So substitute $\neg B$ for $B$, $C\to\neg B$ for $C$, and $\neg B$ for $D$ in (A2) and follow Donald's steps above. $$\small\begin{array}{r|ll}5.&(\neg B{\to}((C{\to}\neg B){\to}\neg B)){\to}((\neg B{\to}(C{\to}\neg B)){\to}(\neg B{\to}\neg B))& (A2)\\6.&\neg B{\to}((C{\to}\neg B){\to}\neg B)&(A1)\\7.&(\neg B{\to}(C{\to}\neg B)){\to}(\neg B{\to}\neg B)&MP, 5,6\\8.&\neg B{\to} (C{\to} \neg B)&(A1)\\9.&\neg B{\to}\neg B&MP, 7,8\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't think that Donald's answer works in the system given in Mendelson's book just FYI - I see no indication that it is possible to perform arbitrary formula substitutions on anything but the axiomatic schema. In other words, it's likely missing a few steps.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, you can establish

$$X \to Y \vdash (R \to X) \to (R \to Y)$$

Using only A1 and A2.  Then use that schema to establish

$$\lnot B \to B \vdash (\lnot B \to \lnot B) \to (\lnot B \to B)$$

Then with A3 as $$(\lnot B \to \lnot B) \to (\lnot B \to B) \vdash B$$

And just stitch things together.